# What are .deb and .rpm and how are they different from .msi?

Tags: package-management, rpm, dpkg

What are these file formats and how do they differ from the `.msi` format in Windows? Also what are the pros and cons of these package management schemes?

Comment: .deb and .rpm are more similar to .msi than to .exe.

Comment: note: asking "what are the pros and cons of rpm vs deb/dpkg" elsewhere on the internet carries with it the possibility of inciting a flame war.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Files such as `.deb` and `.rpm` are more akin to a `.zip` file. They're a directory tree of files and sub-directories that contain files related to a particular application and/or library of files.

#### Distros

The `.deb` files are meant for distributions of Linux that derive from Debian (Ubuntu, Linux Mint, etc.). The `.rpm` files are used primarily by distributions that derive from  Redhat based distros (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL) as well as by the openSuSE distro.

#### What's special about them?

These files have one other special trait that sets them apart from `.zip` files, in that they can include a specification that contains rules that tell the package manager software running on a system that's installing one of these files to do additional tasks. These tasks would include things such as:

- creating user accounts on the system
- creating/modifying configuration files that aren't actually contained in the `.deb` or `.rpm` file
- set ownership/permissions on the files after installation
- run commands as root on the system that's installing the package
- dependencies, both formats can include names or packages and/or service names that they require to be present on a system, prior to installation.

#### What about .msi files?

`.msi` files are similar to `.deb` & `.rpm` files but likely even more sophisticated. The `.msi` files are utilized by the Windows Installer and offer additional features such as:

- GUI Framework
- generation of uninstall sequences
- A framework within itself - for use by 3rd party installers
- Rollbacks
- Advertisement
- User Interface
- etc.

I'd suggest taking a look at the various Wikipedia pages on these subjects if you want a more in-depth explanation.

#### References

- [Windows Installer - .msi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer)
- [RPM file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpm_%28file_format%29)
- [DEB file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_%28file_format%29)

Comment: Since the answer starts with "Files such as .deb and .rpm are more akin to a .zip file" it might be worth mentioning that deb packages are actually `ar` archives, and rpms are (possibly in part) cpio archives. In the case of debs it is easy to verify that a deb can be unpacked with `ar -x`. In the case of rpm I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: `rpm2cpio package.rpm | cpio -idv`

Comment: @ninjalj - thanks I forgot to add that command. I've used it to unpack rpms when I only wanted a file or two out of them. Usually the .spec files.

Comment: @ninjalj Thanks, I didn't know that one.

Answer (score 35):

The other answers touch upon qualities of `.deb` and `.rpm` that are similar to `.msi`.  They all contain software in a compressed format that can do some extra things.  Those extra things already mentioned included adding users, pre- and post-install tasks, registering the program with the system (e.g. windows registry, xdg-dirs, OpenRC/systemd init, etc).

What differentiates the formats (and is a huge pro) is dependencies.  Both `.deb` and `.rpm` files can and do list names and versions of other programs that must be installed as pre-requisite software.  By themselves, this is just informational, but...

You typically do not directly interact with `.deb` and `.rpm` files the way you do with `.msi` files. In fact, as alluded to earlier, a `.deb` is typically just an archive (ar or tar) compressed with xz with the contained files in a specific directory layout.  Instead you use tools like `dpkg` and `rpm` to manipulate these files.

`dpkg` and `rpm` will install the contents of `.deb` and `.rpm` files and verify all pre-requisite software is installed.  Running these programs is similar to clicking on a `.msi` file.  Users however, do not typically interact with `dpkg` or `rpm` but instead use `apt-get` and `yum` to install packages.  These tools do not have exact analogs on windows.

Both `apt-get` and `yum` are able to fetch files from remote (or local) repositories and use the dependency information stored in the `.deb` and `.rpm` files to fetch and install any pre-requisites not met. With these tools I do not need to know or worry about what other software I need, I can just specify `apt-get install chromium` and know that `apt-get` will make sure I have gtk+, alsa, certain X libraries, etc installed without me having to manually find and install those `.deb` and `.rpm` files.

`apt-get` and `yum` are the big two package managers, you'll also find `emerge` and `pacman` out there, which do the same jobs although with different underlying mechanisms.

Comment: +1 for talking about dependency management.  This should not be overlooked.

Comment: note: I believe `.deb`s are packaged using the `ar` utility. no idea why.

Comment: also, if you're going to count `emerge` as a package manager, maybe you should also consider BSD ports (although I don't know much about them, so I'm not sure if they have the equivalent of a package manager on GNU/Linux).

Comment: @strugee true, I've edited to reflect that. Also techically, portage is package management engine behind `emerge` and it is very similar to ports.  It is all source based and very configurable, but if a command will install/uninstall, handle dependencies and keep a database of installed packages, I'll call it a package manager.  Good comments.

Comment: @casey : Where can i get more information about the underlying mechanisms of dpkg and rpm?

Answer (score 3):

It has quite the same functionalities as an MSI file under Windows :

- it registers the software in a registry,
- it registers which files have been installed with that package.

Under Linux, they also manage dependencies between other packages.

This package managment formats do many other things, but this is the main functionalities.

Answer (score 2):

`.rpm` files are RPM packages, which refer to the package type used by Red Hat and Red Hat-derived distros (e.g. Fedora, RHEL, CentOS). `.deb` files are DEB packages, which are the package type used by Debian and Debian-derivatives (e.g. Debian, Ubuntu).

When downloaded, they are typically installed via the `rpm` and `dpkg` commands respectively on the relevant distros. In other words, they are files that are installed by `rpm` and `dpkg` rather than `.msi` or `.exe` setup files which are executables that install themselves.

RPM and DEB packages differ from MSI in multiple ways.

- As above, they are files that require other tools (i.e. `rpm` and `dpkg`) to install.
- When installed, they are added to a database, which is not the case in MSI files. MSI files list the program in the registry, but an uninstall by Control Panel is unlikely to completely remove *all* installed files from disk. Thus, when RPM and DEB packages are uninstalled, all files are removed cleanly.
- They are typically not downloaded and installed directly, but through package managers like `yum` and `aptitude` respectively - there are so-called repositories that offer packages compiled for the relevant system, and the package manager will install all dependencies automatically from data in the repositories.
- Installed packages typically run several configuration tools, for example if you install GDM on a system already installed with LightDM, the tools ask if you would prefer to use GDM of LightDM.
- When installing packages, other than dependencies some packages are suggested, which show packages not *required* but may be useful to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Both `.deb` and `.rpm` are Software packages for GNU/Linux Distributions, containing software (program(s), application(s), etc.) and  information for the "*installer *" software about the software itself and instructions  about how to install what and where correctly.

- `.deb` → [Debian Software Package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.deb), on Debian (based) Distributions. Installed through e.g. `apt`/`aptitude` (Command line), or *graphically* via e.g. "*Synaptic*" "*Ubuntu Software Center*", "*Gdebi*", …
- `.rpm` → [Red Hat Package Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.rpm): in Fedora / Red Hat (based) Linux Distributions. Installed via e.g. `yum` (command line), or *graphically* via e.g. "*yumex*"
- `.msi` is → [Microsoft Installer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.msi): Quite the same as above, for Microsoft Windows OS

The installers themselves can also handle maintenance, updating and/or removal of packages. Also: here, "*installer*" means the software to accomplish this tasks correctly – it also provides the mentioned information for user itself, of course, to accomplish such tasks manually.

Comment: PackageKit isn't an application. it's an abstraction library for the different package managers across distributions.

Comment: @strugee dang, thought this was the name. I really hope `yumex` is the right name… thanks for the hint

Comment: I believe the default on Fedora is GNOME Software.

Comment: @strugee I tried Fedora for a while, used LXDE and remembered a graphical front-end for package management, but the name was… I guess, whatever works and suits one's desires best :)

Answer (score 1):

`.deb`: Debian package used for Debian-based Linux distros such as Ubuntu, Linux Mint etc.

`.rpm`: `rpm` installer for Red Hat-based Linux distros such as RHEL, Fedora and CentOS

`.msi`: Binary installer for Windows platform

Comment: welcome to Stack Exchange! an explanation of why you've been downvoted: I'm not one of the two people who downvoted, but my guess is that they did so because you're implying that Debian and/or Ubuntu aren't GNU/Linuxes, and that's false. they are. (and there are a lot more distributions than just Debian, Ubuntu and Fedora.) also, you didn't really explain anything.

Comment: Update: edited to remove that implication

Comment: I guess the downvotes are really for just giving a one line description of what the file means, not the actual explanation of how these packages are different from each other. Have a look at the selected answer here, that is the kind of quality they expect from answers :)